# Instagram API to fetch feeds for other users?

Tags: instagram, liferay-6, instagram-api

I am trying to access Instagram feeds for my user and hence I have created a Access Token as per documentation

> https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

I am able to access my feeds by passing access token over

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=
```

However, I would like to fetch other user's feed (read only). So I want to make user as configurable and when I change user, I get respective user's feeds.

Could you please let me know if I have to use different end points?

I have tried

> "https://www.instagram.com/v1/users/{user}/media/recent/"

But it is not working and resulting in page not found.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Suyash Bhalekar

Answer (score 1):

If you don't plan to have more than 10 users you can use [Sandbox mode](https://instagram.com/developer/sandbox/). Access token is connected for given Instagram account, not to your entire app. So other users needs to "log in" to your app and approve access to their personal data. Once they do that you receive access token for their Instagram user and you can use `/self/media/recent` endpoint.

However if you plan to have more than 10 users you need to submit your app for [review](https://instagram.com/developer/review/).